# Не работает пример практической работы requirejs и define модулей

Tags: javascript, requirejs

добрый день,

пытаюсь разобраться на простом примере с практической работой requirejs и define модулей

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Как использовать RequireJS для нашего проекта</title>
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="" class="myclass"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min",
    "place":"place"
   }
 });

 require(["jquery","place"], function(place) {
   place('.myclass');
 });
```

place.js

```
define(["jquery"], function () { 
   function place(mydiv) {
      return $(mydiv).html("Мой пример текста");
   }
});
```

консоль в chrome показывает ошибок нет, но и результат нулевой!

подскажите, пожалуйста, где в моих кодах ошибки?

спасибо

Comment: Мне кажется что в place.js нужно возвращать функцию place.

    define(["jquery"], function () { 
       function place(mydiv) {
          return $(mydiv).html("Мой пример текста");
       }
        return place;
    });

Comment: спасибо за ответ, да вы правы, но почему тогда такой вот, например код в файле place.js: 

define(["jquery"], function ($, mydiv) {
return { 
place : function() {
$(mydiv).html("Мой пример текста");
}
}
});

не работает. 

спасибо за любой совет или идею

Comment: откуда в вашем примере берется mydiv? Где его определили? В вашем случае модуль, которому дали название jquery в кофигурации можно использовать внутри данного модуля как $, а mydiv что такое?